# Override Countdown

Tags: batch-file, overriding, countdown

When making Batch files, I still haven't learnt how to make a question override countdown. What I mean by this is, say you have an ask question sequence like this:

```
set /p LeavingQuestion1= 

if %LeavingQuestion1%==15 goto Question2
```

Is there a way which I can implement a countdown to this question so if they don't answer the question in 5 seconds, it goes to MainMenu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the answer 1 character long? If so, you could do something like this:

```
REM Asks for input. You might want to add on /N to hide the prompt.
choice /c abcz /t 5 /d z

REM Checks if the time ran out, otherwise goes to next question...
if %errorlevel%==4 goto MainMenu ELSE goto question2
```

Replace `abcz` with the possible choices. Each is 1 letter long. E.g. if you did abcz, it would ask for a, b, c, or z. Note that you might want to hide the z because that will be the answer that's automatically selected if you run out of time.

The `/t 5 /d z` makes it select `z` if it waits more than 5 seconds.

The way `choice` outputs is it makes `%errorlevel%` the number of the choice that was selected. So if it ran out of time, then z, the 4th answer, becomes `%errorlevel%`. This is why it checks for the errorlevel to be 4. Also, if you wanted to check for the first choice (in this case `a`), you could do `if %errorlevel%==1`, and `if %errorlevel%==2` for the second choice (b), etc.

Sorry if this was a bit confusing; do `choice /?` for some more info.